# Running AWS commands works ok, but the code seems messy and I don't like the time.sleep bit

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

This is what I've come up with for a class that handles parsing AWS Textract output. So far it only gets the AWS Textract output into a .txt file.

```
import json
import logging as log
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time

log.basicConfig(
  format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s',
  datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
  level=log.DEBUG,
  handlers=[
    log.StreamHandler(),
    log.FileHandler('{}.log'.format(__name__))
  ]
)


class InitialParser:

  def __init__(self, filename, s3_bucket, version=1):
    self.filename = filename
    self.s3_bucket = s3_bucket
    self.version = version

    self.file = None
    self.filepath = None
    self.data = None
    self.output_filename = self.filename.replace('.pdf', '.txt')

  def run(self):
    log.info('Running initial parser on file {}'.format(self.filename))
    if self.run_textract():
      log.info('Textract process successful')
    else:
      log.info('Textract process failed, exiting')
      sys.exit(0)

  def load_file_data(self):
    self.filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '../extracted/{}'.format(filename))
    try:
      with open(self.filepath, 'r') as file:
        self.file = file
        self.data = json.load(file)
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
      log.error('Could not find parsing file: {}'.format(e))

  def run_textract(self):
    """
    Runs AWS Textract commands on the given document and sends the output
    to a .txt file.

    @param s3_bucket: the S3 Bucket where the document is located.
    """
    job_id = ''
    # note: adding "Version":<str> to the AWS object below breaks the command
    aws_object = json.dumps({"S3Object":{"Bucket":self.s3_bucket,"Name":self.filename}}).replace(' ', '')  # can't have any spaces lol picky AWS CLI

    start_textract_command = "aws textract start-document-text-detection --document-location '{}'".format(aws_object)
    get_textract_output_command = 'aws textract get-document-text-detection --job-id '

    try:
      job_id = '"{}"'.format(json.loads(subprocess.check_output([start_textract_command], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).decode('utf-8'))['JobId'])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
      if 'InvalidS3ObjectException' in e.output.decode('utf-8'):
        log.error('InvalidS3ObjectException (could not fetch object metadata from S3).\n Check the document name, AWS CLI configuration region (run `aws configure list`), permissions, and the S3 Bucket name & region.')
      elif 'ProvisionedThroughputExceededException' in e.output.decode('utf-8'):
        log.error('ProvisionedThroughputExceededException (provisioned rate exceeded). You\'re doing that too much.')
      else:
        log.error('Starting Textract failed. Error: {}'.format(e.output.decode('utf-8')))

    time.sleep(10)  # wait for Textract to do its' thing

    if job_id != '':
      try:
        subprocess.call(['touch {}'.format(self.output_filename)], shell=True)
        subprocess.call(['{} > {}'.format(get_textract_output_command+job_id, self.output_filename)], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        return True
      except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        log.error(e.output)
    else:
      return False



if __name__ == '__main__':
  initial_parser = InitialParser(
    filename='test1.pdf',
    s3_bucket='test-bucket',
  )
  initial_parser.run()
```

I'd like a better way of handling the wait period for Textract to finish other than waiting 10 seconds, and it may take longer than that in some instances.

I do know that the output file will have `"JobStatus": "IN PROGRESS"` so I could repeatedly search the output .txt file for "SUCCEEDED", but that could be slow if the file has 40,000+ lines when it's actually done (it will)

Answer (score 2):

```
aws_object = json.dumps({"S3Object":{"Bucket":self.s3_bucket,"Name":self.filename}}).replace(' ', '')  # can't have any spaces lol picky AWS CLI
start_textract_command = "aws textract start-document-text-detection --document-location '{}'".format(aws_object)
```

This is not AWS which is picky, rather you’re not building the command line properly. If you provide a single string and start your `subprocess` using `shell=True`, each space will mark a new argument. Instead, you’d be better off building a list of arguments and let `subprocess` quote them properly:

```
start_textract_command = ['aws', 'textract', 'start-document-text-detection', '--document-location', json.dumps(…)]
```

and then just run `subprocess.check_output(start_textract_command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`.

Speaking of which, instead of using the [older high level API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#older-high-level-api), you should switch to [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

```
process = subprocess.run(start_textract_command, capture_output=True, encoding='utf-8')
try:
    process.check_returncode()
except CalledProcessError:
    if 'InvalidS3ObjectException' in process.stderr:
       …
else:
    job_id = json.loads(process.stdout)['JobId']
    with open(self.output_filename, 'wb') as output_file:
       process = subprocess.run(['aws', 'textract', 'get-document-text-detection', '--job-id', str(job_id)], stdout=output_file, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    if process.returncode:
        log.error(process.stderr.decode('utf-8'))
```

---

Now for the `time.sleep` part, [AWS Textract provides two modes of operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/how-it-works.html): synchronous and asynchronous. You can start by using the synchronous [`detect-document-text`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_DetectDocumentText.html) operation if it fits your need and you won't have to deal with the timing at all.

Otherwise, if you need to stick to [`start-document-text-detection`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_StartDocumentTextDetection.html), the completion of the process is published as a notification. I’m not at all versed in how SNS works but they have [a tutorial to get you started on using Amazon SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-tutorials.html) so you can create a channel, specify it in your textract job and wait for the completion event.

Comment: thanks for the tips, this really cleans up the code.

Comment: just wanted to add that the `capture_output` arg for `subprocess.run` does not exist in Python 3.6.X and using `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @star_trac You should also add `stderr=PIPE`, to account for the error case as well.